# Style bootsrap radio buttons via images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to style some radio buttons using images, via background-color property.
Using bootstrap, the code sequence looks somewhat like this:

```
<div id="something">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="some_id" value="Yes" type="radio">
            Yes
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="some_id2" checked="" value="No" type="radio">
            No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is edit it's icons for checked, unchecked, focused, checked-focused and disabled states. I don't want the text to have a background, just the icon in front of it.

css:

```
.radio label {
    line-height: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
}
.radio label{
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/1024px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png");
  background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.radio label:checked{
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/170px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png");
  }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qL2wab24/

Comment: is this helpful http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/image-checkbox ?

Comment: `label` cannot be checked, only `radio` boxes inside your labels can be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 radio button styles,

```css
radio{
    position: reletive;
    overflow: hidden;}
.radio label {
    line-height: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
}
.radio label{
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/1024px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png");
  background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked~label{
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/170px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png");
  }
.radio label:focus{
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/170px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png");
  }
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked~label:focus{
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/1024px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png");
  }
  
.radio input[type="radio"]{position: absolute;top: 0; left: 0; z-index: -1; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;}
```

```html
<div id="something">
    <div class="radio">
            <input id="some_id" value="Yes" type="radio" name="name">
        <label for="some_id">
            Yes
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio">
            <input id="some_id2" checked="" value="No" type="radio" name="name">
        <label for="some_id2">
            No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to adapt this to my project.

Comment: The only thing is, in bootstrap, the label tag surrounds the input one, it's not one after another.

Comment: then i am afraid it will be a problem :(

Comment: no worries, I will adapt my project to fit this format. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add a css:

```
input[type=radio]
{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I have updated your js fiddle please check:

https://jsfiddle.net/qL2wab24/4/

Comment: I know how to hide the original checkmark. My goal is to show images instead of it, one for each of the states I described above.